# Calculating $\iint_{D} x \sqrt{4x^2 +xy}\, dy\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

The problem is the following, calculate the integral $$\iint_{D} x \sqrt{4x^2 +xy}\, dy\,dx $$  on $D$ where $D=\lbrace x=a\cos(t),\;y=a\sin(2t)\rbrace, x \geq 0$.

My attempt is the following.
Since $t\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2 ] $, so now we have that any point $y \in D$, $$|y|<2x \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2 } $$ and too
$$4x^2 +xy \geq 4x^2+x|y|=2x^2 (2-\sqrt{1-(x/a)^2 })>0 $$ therefore $4x^2 +xy$ is continue in $D$ and we can integrate it.

So now we take
$$\begin{align}
& \int_{-2x \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2 } }^{  2x \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2 } } x \sqrt{4x^2 +xy}\,dy\\
=&\left(4x^2+x\left(2x\sqrt{1-(x/a)^2 }\right) \right)^{\!3/2} - \left(4x^2 +x\left(2x \sqrt{1-(x/a)^2 } \right)\right)^{\!3/2}.
\end{align}$$
So the following is let $x=a\cos(t)$ and integrate respect $t$, so I  say now that $t\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2] $.
But when I integrate it,work not simplify.
Any help is very helpful.
Thanks for read.

Comment: What are your ranges for $a,t$?

Comment: $a$ is any real number and $t\in [-\pi/2,\pi/2] $

Comment: So in your description, $D$ is not the *region* but the *boundary curve*.

Comment: It is a region $D$ like a area of  Lissajous curve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand right, $a$ is a fixed parameter.

You can use [Green's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_theorem).

Let $M(x,y)=0$.

Let $L(x,y)=-\frac{2}{3}\left(4x^2+xy\right)^{3/2}$, so that $\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}=-x\sqrt{4x^2+xy}$.

So
$$\begin{align}
&\iint_Dx\sqrt{4x^2+xy}\,dy\,dx\\
&=\iint_D\left(\frac{\partial M}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial y}\right)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\oint_C(L\,dx+M\,dy)\\
&=\oint_C -\frac{2}{3}\left(4x^2+xy\right)^{3/2}\,dx\\
&=-\frac{2}{3}\int_{t=-\pi/2}^{t=\pi/2} \left(4a^2\cos^2t+a^2\cos t\sin 2t\right)^{3/2} \cdot -a\sin t\,dt\\
&=\frac{2a^4}{3}\int_{t=-\pi/2}^{t=\pi/2} \left(4\cos^2t+2\cos^2 t\sin t\right)^{3/2} \cdot \sin t\,dt\\
&=\frac{2a^4}{3}\int_{t=-\pi/2}^{t=\pi/2} \cos^3t\cdot\left(4+2\sin t\right)^{3/2} \cdot \sin t\,dt&u=\sin t\\
&=\frac{2a^4}{3}\int_{u=-1}^{u=1} \left(1-u^2\right)\left(4+2u\right)^{3/2} u\,du&v=4+2u\\
&=\frac{2a^4}{3}\int_{v=2}^{v=6} \left(1-\left(\frac{v-4}{2}\right)^2\right)v^{3/2} \frac{v-4}{2}\,\frac12dv\\
&=\frac{a^4}{24}\int_{v=2}^{v=6} \left(4-(v-4)^2\right)v^{3/2} (v-4)\,dv\\
\end{align}$$

Now you can multiply this out to simple powers of $v$ to integrate.

Comment: Can you check my method, because I use it and I don't know about if it be correct

Answer (score 0):

Como l región $D$ está dada por una curva paramétrica, entonces vamos a eliminar el parámetro $t$, consideremos
\begin{equation}
y=aSin(2t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y=2aSin(t)Cos(t)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
y^2=4a^2Sin^{2}(t)Cos^{2}(t)
\end{equation}
Recordemos que $x^2=a^2Cos^2(t)$ por la curva paramétrica.
\begin{equation}
y^2=4Sin^2(t)(x^2)
\end{equation}
Además $Sin^2(t)+Cos^2(t)=1$ por lo que

\begin{equation}
y^2=4x^2(1-Cos^2(t))
\end{equation}
Usando que $x=aCos(t)$ tenemos que $\frac{x}{a}=Cos(t)$ por tanto
\begin{equation}
y^2=4x^2(1-\frac{x^2}{a^2})
\end{equation}
Sacamos raiz cuadrada y notemos que $x \geq 0$
\begin{equation}
y=\pm 2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}
\end{equation}
Ahora bien, ya que sabemos que curvas estan modelando la región pasamos a definir los límites de integración, veamos que $D$ es una región $x$-Simple,pues mientras $x\in[0,a]$ y varía de la curva $- 2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$ a la curva $2x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$, ahora planteamos la integral que buscamos calcular en la región $D$ bajo $f$ que queda $$\int_{0}^{a} \int_{- 2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}x \sqrt{4x^2+xy} dy dx$$
Ahora procedemos a hacer los cálculos para la integral, primero vamos a calcular $$ \int_{- 2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}x \sqrt{4x^2+xy} dy $$
Ahora,notemos que como $|y|<2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}$, esto implica que la región es simétrica, por tanto podemos calcular $$2*\int_{0}^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}x \sqrt{4x^2+xy} dy $$ ahora,podemos calcular respecto de $y$ una primitiva por ser $f$ continua, en $D$, así que haciendo un simple cambio de variable $u=4x^2+xy$ tenemos que $du=xdy$, por tanto podemos calcular la antiderivada, por tanto $$4/3 \int_{0}^{a} (4x^2+xy)^{(3/2)}|_{0}^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}$$ y valuando en los límites de integración tenemos el siguiente resultado:$$4/3 \int_{0}^{a}(4x^2+2x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}})^{3/2}-8x^3$$.\
Por lo pronto vamos a valuar la siguiente integral: $$\int_{0}^{a}(4x^2+2x^2\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}})^{3/2}$$, consideremos el siguiente cambio de variable $x=acos(t)$ implica que $dx=-asin(t)$ y  además cuando $x \to a$ , $t \to 0$ y también $x\to 0$ implica $t \to \pi/2$ remplazando en nuestra integral  y simplificando nuestro integrando tenemos:  $$2\sqrt{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{0} (a^3cos^3(t)(2+sin(t))(2+sin(t)){(1/2})(-asin(t)dt$$ $$-2\sqrt{2}a^4\int_{\pi/2}^{0}cos^2(t)sin(t)(2+sin(t))^{3/2}cos(t)dt$$ cambiando el orden de integración $$2\sqrt{2}a^4\int_{0}^{\pi/2}cos^2(t)sin(t)(2+sin(t))^{3/2}cos(t)dt$$ , sea $l=2+sin(t)$ entonces $dl=cos(t)dt$ y además cuando $t \to 0$ , $l \to 2$ y cuando $t \to \pi/2$, $l\to 3$ transformando nuestra integral ahora obtenemos $$2\sqrt{2}a^4\int_{2}^{3}(1-(l-2)^2)(l-2)(l^{3/2})dl$$ haceindo las operaciones algebráicas $$2\sqrt{2}a^4\int_{2}^{3} 6l^{3/2}-11l^{5/2}+6l^{7/2}-l^{9/2} dl$$ haciendo la evaluación de la integral $$2\sqrt{2}a^4[\frac{216}{385}\sqrt{3}+\frac{32}{1155} \sqrt{2}]$$ simplificando la expresión $$2\sqrt{2}a^4[\frac{8}{1155}(4\sqrt{2}+81 \sqrt{3})]$$ finalmente queda $$[\frac{16\sqrt{2}a^4}{1155}(4\sqrt{2}+81 \sqrt{3})]$$ ahora vamos a resolver la segunda intgral que es más sencilla $$\int{0}^{a} 8x^3dx$$ esta integral es muy inmediata, por lo que queda $$8 \int_{0}^{a}x^3$$ de esto $$8[\frac{1}{4}x^{4}|_{0}^{a}]=2a^4$$ juntando ambas partes y calculando la resta  $$\int_{0}^{a} \int_{- 2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}^{2x\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{a^2}}}x \sqrt{4x^2+xy} dy dx=  \frac{4}{3}a^4([\frac{16\sqrt{2}}{1155}(4\sqrt{2}+81 \sqrt{3})]-2)$$.\